# Fitting a derivative of a curve to data

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization, numerical-methods

Some derivatives cannot be integrated to an analytic function but have the function embedded in the derivative itself.  I need to know how to fit those derivative functions to a set of data.  Here is an example:

I have a time series data, lets call it yData.

I have a non-integrable derivative, in this example:
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{(ay(t)(K-y(t)))}{K - y(t) +cy(t)}$$

I need to come up with an objective function (figure of merit, $\chi^2$) to optimize, but don't know what to use for the "y" terms in the derivative.

What do I do?  The only thing I can think of is to use the data itself:

$$ \chi^2 = \sum \frac{\left(yData_i - \frac{ayData_i(K-yData_i)}{K - yData_i +c*yData_i}\right)^2}{\sigma_i}$$

Does this make any sense?

Comment: Subtractions of the type $y(t) - y'(t)$ do not make sense because the  dimensions are different. Example: if $y$ is measured in meters, then $y'(t)$ is measured in meters per second. How did you generate the data in the first place?

Comment: This is the equation of a sigmoid by Dr. P.D. Birch published in 1999 (eqn. 11).  I’m not sure where you see $y(t) - y’(t)$ in the equation.   I did edit a small error in the O.P. But that did not add or remove any $y(t)-y’(t).

Comment: Correction, the sigmoid was published by Dr. Colin P.D. Birch. The actual data is a time series of a sigmoid with a very low inflection point.  The Birch sigmoid should fit better than Richards or Weibul but we need to try it out.

Comment: No, replacing the derivative by the function does not make any sense. An option could be to estimate the derivatives numerically.

Comment: I could numerically estimate the derivative of the data, but I do not see how that would help me fit the model to the data.

Answer (score 1):

The ODE is separable thus

$$
\frac{A dy}{y}+\frac{B dy}{K-y} = \frac{K+(c-1)y}{y(K-y)}dy = adt
$$

with $A=1$ and $B=c$ then

$$
\ln y - c\ln(y-K) = a t + c_0\Rightarrow \frac{y}{(y-K)^c}=c_1 e^{a t}
$$

The determination of $c_1$ is done as $\frac{y(0)}{(K-y(0))^c}=c_1 $ and then

$$
\frac{y}{(y-K)^c}=\frac{y(0)}{(y(0)-K)^c} e^{a t}
$$

now if $\{t_j, y_j\},\ \ j=1,\cdots,n$ is the data to adjust we can proceed defining

$$
\mathcal{O}(a,c,K,y_0)=\sum_{j=1}^n\|\frac{y_j}{(y_j-K)^c}-\frac{y_0}{(y_0-K)^c} e^{a t_j}\|
$$

and then follow with

$$
\min_{a,c,K,y_0}\mathcal{O}(a,c,K,y_0)
$$

to determine the best parameters.

Comment: Thank you.  I want to try it but am a MATLAB user and am neither familiar with mathematica nor have any experience  with the MATLAB ODE solvers.  It looks like 
solp = ParametricNDSolveValue[ode, y, {t, 0, tmax}, {a, c, k, y0}];
returns a function.  Do you know if any of the MATLAB ode solvers (e.g. ode45) act like ParametricNDSolveValue?

Comment: I was long ago a Matlab user.  I don't know if now Matlab has solvers with this ability. Googling I found things like that https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/255128-parametric-system-of-differential-equation-finally-plotting-against-the-parameter . Perhaps in Python can be found some tool to solve conveniently that.

Comment: @A.Goldstein I changed the answer focusing the ODE proposed. I hope this helps.